# Async - await not executing callback in a for loop

Tags: javascript, file, async-await, callback

I have used the `async function` and waiting for one `API` to hit and display its current file name which got uploaded then increase the counter I and go for the next file.

**ISSUE:** The `async` and `await` is working fine but the **callbacks are called after all the requests have been made**.

How can I hit the `API` and get its name printed then go for another file to hit the API?

PS: **I can't change callback to promise, it's a defined structure in my organization as of now**.

**Code**:

```js
uploadCallback = () => {
  console.log(currentFile)
}

const loop = async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.fln.length; i++) {
    currentFile = obj.fln;
    await uploadAPI(obj, this.uploadCallback);
    console.log('currentFile:', i, currentFile);
  }
};
```

Comment: If you can't change it to a Promise, wrap it with one instead.

Comment: Here's example code showing how to promisify a function that uses a callback: https://jsfiddle.net/7p89uL5h/

Comment: Simply `await new Promise(resolve => { uploadAPI(obj, resolve); })`.

Comment: native for loop is not meant for this. use for...of

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
uploadCallback = () => {
  console.log(currentFile)
}

const loop = async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.fln.length; i++) {
    currentFile = obj.fln;
    const res = await uploadAPI(obj);
    this.uploadCallback(res);
    console.log('currentFile:', i, currentFile);
  }
};
```

This will make sure that the callback is called only after uploadAPI finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to integrate promises. Here's an example with the Pokemon API...

```
 let thisstateflnlength = 5
    
    const getAPI = (counter = 0) => {
      if (counter <= thisstateflnlength) {
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto").then(response => response.json()).then(data =>{
          console.log(data.forms[0])
          console.log(counter)
        }).then(data => getAPI(counter+1))
    
      }
    }
    
    getAPI()
```

The counter logs from 0-5 and each API call is executed asynchronously.